# Как исключить ненужные слова регулярным выражением?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пожалуйста, помогите чайнику разобраться с исключениями в regexp.

Задача обработать одним регулярным выражением список строк, 
чтобы на выходе был экстракт только слов, которые стоят перед "`</a>`" или перед "`&nbsp;`".
Строки:

```
<a href='/'>Нужные слова</a> <span>Какие-то&nbsp;еще&nbsp;слова</span>
<a href='/'>Вот нужные слова&nbsp;абракадабра</a> <span>Какие-то&nbsp;еще&nbsp;слова</span>
<a href='/'>Другие нужные слова</a> <span>Какие-то&nbsp;еще&nbsp;слова</span>
<a href='/'>Ещё нужные слова&nbsp;другие крякозябры</a> <span>Какие-то&nbsp;еще&nbsp;слова</span>
```

Желаемый результат:

```
Нужные слова
Вот нужные слова
Другие нужные слова
Ещё нужные слова
```

Пытаюсь парсить в SEO Spider.
Дальше `<a href='/'>(.*?)&nbsp;` я не ушел.

Answer (score 1):

Забыли альтернативу `</a>`. Главное в этом выражении `?` в `.*?`, он делает выражение не жадным.

```
<a href='\/'>(.*?)(?:&nbsp;|<\/a>)
```

Язык не указан, `/` экранированы `\`.